# How to create fragment interaction?

Tags: android, android-fragments

These are the imports I have for the fragment class.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

Class being initialized

```
public class FragmentDemo extends Fragment {
```

Public constructor is empty and must stay that way

```
public FragmentDemo() {
    }
```

It must be attached to an activity, the interface depends on said activity

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

Inflating layout for fragment

```
        View result = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_demo, container, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Button button = (Button)result.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        textView.setText("HEY, THIS IS A TEST!");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("FRAGMENT", "BUTTON IS WORKING!");
                // why no toast?
            }
        });

        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create two classes to make it more clear, one for the interaction of fragments, and a main class.

The first one should look like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link InteractionFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link InteractionFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */

public class InteractionFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String ARG_LAST_NAME = "lastName";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public InteractionFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment InteractionFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    // Factory method
    public static InteractionFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        InteractionFragment fragment = new InteractionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_NAME, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_LAST_NAME, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            name = getArguments().getString(ARG_NAME);
            lastName = getArguments().getString(ARG_LAST_NAME);
        }
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_interaction, container, false);
        TextView nameText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView lastNameText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.last_name);

        nameText.setText(name);
        lastNameText.setText(lastName);

        Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mListener.somethingHappened("THE BUTTON WAS PRESSED, HOW EXCITING!");
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public void printALog(){
        Log.wtf("PRINTING", "ITS WORKING!");
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void somethingHappened(String message);
    }
}
```

While the second one should look like this:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.TransactionTooLargeException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InteractionFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    InteractionFragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void addFragment(Fragment f){

        // add a fragment through code
        // fragment manager - the guy in charge of any fragment related logic
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();


        // transactions
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

        // actually do the thing
        //fragment = InteractionFragment.newInstance("Juan","Perez");
        // 3rd parameter - fragment
        transaction.add(R.id.container, f, "dude");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void somethingHappened(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void doSomethingOnFragment(View v){
        fragment.printALog();
    }

    public void swapFragments(View v){

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();


        Fragment f = manager.findFragmentByTag("dude");

        if(f != null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "FRAGMENT BEING REMOVED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.remove(f);
            transaction.commit();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "NO FRAGMENT TO REMOVE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void addFragment1(View v){
        fragment = InteractionFragment.newInstance("Juan","Perez");
        addFragment(fragment);
    }

    public void addFragment2(View v){
        FragmentDemo fd = new FragmentDemo();
        addFragment(fd);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what is your question exactly, so I will assume first that your problem is related to your "Why no toast?" comment. 
The thing is you are using the log function, this prints in logcat console, not through toasts. 
If you want to display a toast, use

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, durationInMs).show();
```

And because you are in a Fragment the Context used is the `activity` which has this fragment so to get context we use `getActivity()`. Hence the Toast will be:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what is your question exactly, so I will assume first that your problem is related to your "Why no toast?" comment. 
The thing is you are using the log function, this prints in logcat console, not through toasts. 
If you want to display a toast, use

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, durationInMs).show();
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)